# How to check for a boolean field?

Tags: templates, plugin

I am writing a plugin, and everything is working fine so far. Some of my source data includes booleans. So I want to be able to test for true or false.

```
{if show_data}
   <p>This is some data</p>
{/if}
```

But it won't work. Are booleans not supported or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

Here is a sample of how I would like to assign a boolean.

```
$array = array('show_data' => true);
$str = $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, $array);

return $str;
```

Comment: Can you show us what your data array looks like? Are you using `ee()->TMPL->parse_variables()` to return it in your plugin?

Comment: Seems to be a common question. I'm having the same issues with the 'matrix' plugin. Have you tried comparison operators? {if show_data != "false"}
or {if 'show_data' != ""} Also, what version of EE are you using?

Comment: We are using 2.7.2 I am just using a number for now. It sounds like booleans are not supported.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, I read that you must return boolean values from plugins and modules as 'TRUE' and 'FALSE'
[EE Template Class - Conditional Variables](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/template.html#conditional-variables)

Comment: I don't have enough rep to upvote yet, but MB34 is correct. I've had this issue before in the past too.

Comment: So a string of 'FALSE' can be used as a boolean then. It looks like a hack. But I'll have to use it for now.

Comment: Not a hack if that is the way it is supposed to be done per the tool being used.

Comment: Sure, it wouldn't be a hack by us EE users, but a hack by the makers of EE.

Comment: Not if you understand the template parsing mechanism.

Comment: This answer is not correct and these comments are misleading. Please see my answer (and forgive my arrogance!).

Answer (score 2):

It is **not** the case that you need to set your booleans as 'true'/'false' strings, it's that your variables array needs to be nested in its own array like this:

```
$array = array(array('show_data' => true));
$str = $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, $array);    
return $str;
```

You'll now find that outputting {show_data} in a template will return 1, and as such can be used in conditionals like so:

```
{if show_data}It's true{/if}
{if show_data == 0}It's false{/if}
{if show_data == ''}It's false{/if}
{if !show_data}It's false (as of EE 2.9+){/if}
```

Docs: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/template.html#master-variables-array