# How to use negation with a boolean in a tag?

Tags: conditionals

I am writing a plugin, and everything is working fine so far. Some of my source data includes booleans. So I want to be able to test for a value of false. This is the plugin code.

```
$array = array('show_data' => 'FALSE');
$str = $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, $array);

return $str;
```

and this is the template code:

```
{if not show_data}
   <p>This is some data</p>
{/if}
```

or

```
{if !show_data}
   <p>This is some data</p>
{/if}
```

But it won't work. Is this not supported or am I doing something wrong?

Currently I have this workaround

```
{if show_data}{if:else}
   <p>This is some data</p>
{/if}
```

Comment: What is the return value of $str when you want it to return false? You might need to return ''.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExpressionEngine interprets the returned value as the string "FALSE". You probably need to set your var like this:

```
$array = array('show_data' => '');
```

Or you need to format your if statement like

```
{if show_data == "FALSE"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see my answer to your other related question which answers this too. (You need to set your vars array as a multidimensional array):

[How to check for a boolean field?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/17655/how-to-check-for-a-boolean-field/17720#17720)